# Unable to authorize using OAuth (Google API)

Tags: curl, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to use Curl in order to authorize using Oauth, but I'm getting a "Required parameter is missing: grant_type" response from Google. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www.googleapis.com', 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('client_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com', 'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'refresh_token' => $auth->refresh_token, 'grant_type' => 'refresh_token'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

Comment: Use the Google Oauth Playground to go through an Oauth flow and note the http requests. Then get yours to match.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` which results in the content type being set to `multipart/form-data` because it is applied after the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option. You need to apply `http_build_query` to the array first which will result in a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. So use:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('client_id' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com', 'client_secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'refresh_token' => $auth->refresh_token, 'grant_type' => 'refresh_token')));
```